# Rails 3. I think this should be a lot easier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dry

I try to learn RoR and have the following code. I only think it can be a lot easier. What I understand from RoR is that you should try not to repeat and make things as easy as it can be. So maybe someone has some advise on this:

```
    if params[:select_date].present?
  if params[:select_date] == '1'
    params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = Date.today.beginning_of_month
  end
  if params[:select_date] == '2'
    params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = Date.today - 1.months
  end
  if params[:select_date] == '3'
    params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = Date.today - 3.months
  end
  if params[:select_date] == '0'
    params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = params[:search][:date_started_at_gte]
    params[:search][:date_started_at_lte] = params[:search][:date_started_at_lte]
  end
else
    params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = Date.today.beginning_of_month
    params[:search][:date_started_at_lte] = Date.today
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
gte = lte = ''

case params[:select_date]
when '1'
  gte = Date.today.beginning_of_month
when '2'
  gte = Date.today - 1.months
#...
when '0'
  gte = params[:search][:date_started_at_gte]
  lte = params[:search][:date_started_at_lte]
else
  gte = Date.today.beginning_of_month
  lte = Date.today
end
```

I used some new variables `gte, lte` here. I strongly recommend you not to change the value of params!

Comment: Hi Billy. Thanks! Why you recommend not to change parameters? What can be the possible problem with doing that?

Comment: @user1640644, a param stands for what to get from request. Changing the source of information is not good practice when you can easily use any variable to process them.

Comment: Well, what If I don't change parameters I have a new problem: I start the controller with: params[:search][:date_started_at_gte] = Date.today.beginning_of_month. So if I don't change parameters, how can I start with Date.today at begin?

Comment: @Jerry, you assigned a value to params in controller, that's wrong.

Comment: Could you please explain me why it is wrong to assign a value to params in controller? Maybe some pages where I can find some more info about this? Thanks!

Comment: @Jerry, that's common sense. When you received an email, you reply it according to its content, instead of changing the incoming email itself. Same as params. Params are parts of requests, they are facts, they have done their job to send you message. why you want to change them?

Comment: Well, it is something to think about. Only I have no idea how to change that at this moment. In above case user can define parameters for start and end date [date_started_at_gte] & [date_started_at_lte]. What I want to do is to add some predefined periods. So I created a new dropdown that has options as 'this month', 'last 3 months',etc. This dropdown is parameter "[:select_date]". So when user selects 'last_month' from the dropdown (parameter [:select_date"]), I just predefined the parameters [date_started_at_gte] & [date_started_at_lte] from the controller.